# Gradient estimate for parabolic equations.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $A$ be a positive definite, constant coefficients matrix.  Suppose that a Sobolev function $u$ solves
$$
\partial_t u - \text{div}(A\nabla u)=0
$$
in the distributional sense on $B_1\times (-1,0)$. Is it the case that the following inequality holds?

> $$\int_{B_r\times(-r^2,0)} |\nabla u|^2 \le Cr^{n+2} \int_{B_1\times (-1,0)}  |\nabla u|^2 $$
>   for $0<r<1$, $B_r$ the ball of radius $r$.

Comment: Do you have a sign error? If $A$ is positive then the equation you have written is backwards-parabolic, but the cylinders used in your estimate seem suited for a forwards-parabolic equation.

Comment: Anyway, do you know how to prove it in the case of the standard heat equation, i.e. $A=I$? If so, you should be able to transform to this equation by a linear change of coordinates. This will change the balls to ellipses, but ellipses of eccentricity determined by $A;$ so you can fit balls inside/outside with comparable radii and thus obtain the estimate (with a worse $C$.)

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Right, there was a sign error, thank you very much. For the question, no I don't know how to prove it for heat equation either, I have just started learning parabolic type equation. Could you please give  some hint or key idea for $A=I$?

Comment: Are you following a book? The easiest way to prove this probably depends on what you already know. You will most likely need to study the function $f = |\nabla u|^2$ - show that it satisfies $\partial_t f \le \operatorname{div}(A \nabla f)$ and then use this somehow to obtain the estimate.